# Anti-aliased image of a spline shape

Tags: python

My goal is to create 3 images, one is an anti-aliased image of a random spline and then two others that scaled between 0 and 1 for how "horizontal" or "vertical" the spline is at each point.

```
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline, griddata
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def create_random_line():

    # Create random spline
    x = np.array([1, 15, 30, 49])
    y = np.random.uniform(1, 50, 4)
    f = CubicSpline(x, y, bc_type='natural')

    x_new = np.linspace(0, 49, 100)
    y_new = f(x_new)
    y_new_deriv = f(x_new, 1)
    y_angles = np.array([math.atan2(tt, 1) for tt in y_new_deriv])

    # Plot the spline, derivative and angle
    plt.figure(2)
    plt.clf()
    plt.subplot(3,1,1)
    plt.plot(x, y, 'x')
    plt.xlim((0, 50))
    plt.ylim((0, 50))
    plt.plot(x_new, y_new)
    plt.subplot(3,1,2)
    plt.plot(x_new, y_new_deriv)
    plt.subplot(3,1,3)
    plt.plot(x_new, np.rad2deg(y_angles))
    plt.ylim((-90, 90))
    plt.show()

    # Create image of spline
    image = np.zeros((50, 50))
    scaled_angle_maps = np.zeros((50, 50, 2))
    for xx, yy, rr in zip(y_new, x_new, np.rad2deg(y_angles)):

        image[int(np.round(xx)), int(np.round(yy))] = 1
        scaled_angle_maps[int(np.round(xx)), int(np.round(yy)), 0] = np.clip(1 - (np.abs(rr)/90), 0, 1)
        scaled_angle_maps[int(np.round(xx)), int(np.round(yy)), 1] = np.clip(np.mod(np.abs(rr),90)/90, 0, 1)

    return image, scaled_angle_maps

# Create random spline image
image, scaled_angle_maps = create_random_line()

# Plot
plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()
plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.imshow(image)
plt.gray()
plt.colorbar()
plt.ylim((0,50))

plt.subplot(2,2,3)
plt.imshow(scaled_angle_maps[:,:,0])
plt.ylim((0,50))
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('horizontal')

plt.subplot(2,2,4)
plt.imshow(scaled_angle_maps[:,:,1])
plt.ylim((0,50))
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('vertical')
plt.show()
```

[image: image of spline]

But, I would like this anti-aliased. I have been reading about Wu's algorithm, but most implementations appear to be for straight lines. I tried creating it from the matplotlib canvas, but that did not work out well.

Then, second, I would like to have an arbitrary thickness to the spline in the image, though I suppose I could just `scipy.ndimage.grey_dilation` after the image is created.

So, am I missing an easy method of creating a random spline image? It feels like there should be a simpler method to do this.